# Typing and IDE support while __init_subclass__

Tags: python, inheritance, pytest

My goal is to simplify tests. I noticed every api test uses TestClient class and query wrapper.

```
import pytest

class UserWrapper:
    def get_user(self):
        ...

class EventWrapper:
    def get_event(self):
        ...

class Base:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def __init_subclass__(cls, wrapper, **kwargs):
        cls.wrapper = wrapper

class TestUserApi(Base, wrapper=UserWrapper()):
    def test_create(self):
        resp = self.client.post(...)
        assert self.wrapper.get_user(resp.json())

class TestEventApi(Base, wrapper=EventWrapper()):
    def test_create(self):
        resp = self.client.post(...)
        assert self.wrapper.get_event(resp.json())
```

The problem is I would like to type somewhere wrapper class to have IDE support for it (like go to declaration and autocomplete). I tried

```
class TestEventApi(Base, wrapper: EventWrapper=EventWrapper()):
```

But it doesn't parse. I tried:

```
def __init_subclass__(cls, wrapper: Union[UserWrapper, EventWrapper], **kwargs):
```

but my pyright complained: `cannot access member get_user of type EventWrapper`

What can I do without creating extra class for every test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even bother with `__init_subclass__`?

```python
class Base:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, client):
        self.client = client

class TestUserApi(Base):
    wrapper = UserWrapper()

    def test_create(self):
        resp = self.client.post(...)
        assert self.wrapper.get_user(resp.json())

class TestEventApi(Base):
    wrapper = EventWrapper()

    def test_create(self):
        resp = self.client.post(...)
        assert self.wrapper.get_event(resp.json())
```

Though if you really insist, you can probably do this too (as per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types)):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Base(Generic[T]):
    def setup(self, client):
        self.client = client

    wrapper: T

    def __init_subclass__(cls, wrapper: T, **kwargs):
        cls.wrapper = wrapper

class TestUserApi(Base[UserWrapper], wrapper=UserWrapper()):
    def test_create(self):
        resp = self.client.post(...)
        assert self.wrapper.get_user(resp.json())

class TestEventApi(Base[EventWrapper], wrapper=EventWrapper()):
    def test_create(self):
        resp = self.client.post(...)
        assert self.wrapper.get_event(resp.json())
```

Whether your tooling supports this is another matter; mypy for example pretty much gives up on type-checking `self.wrapper` when given this code.

Comment: Right, I kinda fell into trap of use fancy tools. However woud be nice to know is it possible to use mypy with __init_subclass__. Btw. what happened you answered that after half year? I mean, how did you dredge up that question?